# Ctrl, Alt, etc. not working until I press Esc on Windows 8 HP ProBook 6570b

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab

Issues I am facing:

1. Alt-tab works only when I press it twice
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> works only after I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.
3. Also I noticed while I was playing a game, if I press left key the control goes to the extreme right of the map, like I am holding down the left key.

I read online that this happens when some other program is using your keys and you need to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to activate your keys. This works, but it decreases my productivity.
Any permanent solutions please?